# is copying MSTest executable and related dlls is the only solution to run ms tests in non visual studio environment?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, command-line, integration-testing, mstest

I need to come of with the approach where:

I need to run Visual Studio Unit/Integration tests in environment where visual studio will not be installed. 
After lots of fiddling around i came up with one approach that is to copy MSTest.exe and related dlls into the machine and run the tests from command line.

As shown here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486.aspx)

But wondering is this the only solution to run visual studio tests, i.e Normal MSTests in the environment where there is no visual studio?

Any help from experienced geeks will really help :) :)

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/385c5569-e758-4133-8b58-e74afdb298cf/mstest-installtion-without-even-installing-vsts2010